# How to make button appear on condition in a page view controller in flutter?

Tags: flutter

My page view has back and next buttons.
On the first page, I'd like `back`button not to appear and on the last page, I'd like next to be replaced by `enter app`button.

I have played around with controller.hasClients but didn't find the solution.

My code as follows:

```dart
/// This is the stateless widget that the main application instantiates.
class Introduction extends StatelessWidget {
  /// The pages to display
  final List<IntroductionStandardPage> pages;

  Introduction({required this.pages, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(children: [
      PageView(

          /// [PageView.scrollDirection] defaults to [Axis.horizontal].
          /// Use [Axis.vertical] to scroll vertically.
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          controller: controller,

          // Render all pages
          children: [...pages.map((page) => page.build(context))]),
      SafeArea(
          child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  // if (pages.hasClients &&
                  //     controller.page != null &&
                  //     controller.page! > 0)
                  ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () => controller.previousPage(
                          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
                          curve: Curves.ease),
                      child: Text('previous')),
                  Expanded(child: Spacer()),
                  // if (controller.hasClients &&
                  //     controller.page != null &&
                  //     controller.page! < pages.length - 1)
                  ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (controller.page == pages.length - 1)
                          enterApp(context);
                        else
                          controller.nextPage(
                              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
                              curve: Curves.ease);
                      },
                      child: Text((controller.hasClients &&
                              controller.page != null &&
                              controller.page! == pages.length - 1)
                          ? 'Enter'
                          : 'next')),

                  if (controller.hasClients &&
                      controller.page != null &&
                      controller.page! == pages.length - 1)
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () => enterApp(context), child: Text('go'))
                ],
              ))),
    ]));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Introduction widget needs to become statefull, and you need to register to listen to your page controller. When your Intorduction widget is stateless, it will render only once, and it will never redraw after a page is changed.

I also added Visibility widget to 'Previous' button, so your 'Next' button is always in the same place.

And there's no need to do `pages.map((page) => page.build(context))` - the framework will call the build for you. Even if this works, I think it's a mistake - since you are providing the context of the Introduciton widget; I think framework will assign a new context for each of the pages when needed.

Here's the code - you can try it in DartPad:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: const Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Introduction(pages: [
      Center(
        child: Text(
          'Hello, World - page 1!',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
        ),
      ),
      Center(
        child: Text(
          'Page 2',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
        ),
      ),
      Center(
        child: Text(
          'Page 3',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline4,
        ),
      )
    ]);
  }
}

/// This is the stateless widget that the main application instantiates.
class Introduction extends StatefulWidget {
  /// The pages to display
  final List<Widget> pages;

  const Introduction({required this.pages, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Introduction> createState() => _IntroductionState();
}

class _IntroductionState extends State<Introduction> {
  final controller = PageController(initialPage: 0);

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Stack(children: [
      PageView(scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal, controller: controller, children: widget.pages),
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: SafeArea(
            child: Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 0.0, 20.0, 0.0),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Visibility(
                      maintainSize: true,
                      maintainAnimation: true,
                      maintainState: true,
                      visible: (controller.hasClients && controller.page != null && controller.page! > 0),
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () =>
                              controller.previousPage(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250), curve: Curves.ease),
                          child: const Text('previous')),
                    ),
                    //const Expanded(child: Spacer()),
                    //if (controller.hasClients && controller.page != null && controller.page! < widget.pages.length - 1)
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          if (controller.page == widget.pages.length - 1) {
                            //enterApp(context);
                            print('enterApp');
                          } else {
                            controller.nextPage(duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250), curve: Curves.ease);
                          }
                        },
                        child: Text((controller.hasClients &&
                                controller.page != null &&
                                controller.page! == widget.pages.length - 1)
                            ? 'Enter'
                            : 'next')),

                    // if (controller.hasClients && controller.page != null && controller.page! == widget.pages.length - 1)
                    //   ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => print('enterApp') /*enterApp(context)*/, child: const Text('go'))
                  ],
                ))),
      ),
    ]));
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh gotcha! Thanks for the answer, very clear. One question though: I see that if I leave the spacer (to have the buttons on the edges), the animation fails when the button is no longer visible. I gonna use Positioned, but any better idea to replace the spacer?

Comment: You can just use Spacer() in stead of Expanded(child: Spacer()) - this was causing an issue, so I commented it out.
You can also check Row.mainAxisAlignment, something like:
````child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: [
                    Visibility(````